# Firebase crashlytics crashes with exception IllegalStateException: Expected Android API level 21+ but was 19

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

Firebase crashlytics has reported below crash in my android app.

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected Android API level 21+ but was 19
       at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.<clinit>(AndroidPlatform.kt:205)
       at okhttp3.internal.platform.Android10Platform.<clinit>(Android10Platform.kt:65)
       at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform$Companion.findPlatform(Platform.kt:201)
       at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform$Companion.access$findPlatform(Platform.kt:169)
       at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.kt:170)
       at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.kt:220)
       at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.kt:212)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.network.HttpRequest.<clinit>(HttpRequest.java:43)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.network.HttpRequestFactory.buildHttpRequest(HttpRequestFactory.java:43)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.AbstractSpiCall.getHttpRequest(AbstractSpiCall.java:113)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.network.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.invoke(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:80)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.SettingsController$1.then(SettingsController.java:200)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.SettingsController$1.then(SettingsController.java:193)
       at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzp.run(:2)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:64)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:27)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

It can be seen that crash has occurred in crashlytics itself. The min android SDK version of my app is 19, and it looks like crashlytics expects min sdk level to be 21.

I tested the app on an AVD with SDK 19, but app didn't crash. Also, I couldn't find a min SDK version restriction in crashlytics documentation too.

What is the cause of this issue? Is there any way I can fix it?

Comment: If you have a bug report for Firebase products, you should file that with [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) or on [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk).

Comment: What version of OkHttp are you using? OkHttp 3.13 [raised the minSdkVersion to 21](https://developer.squareup.com/blog/okhttp-3-13-requires-android-5/).

Comment: @ianhanniballake I am not using OkHttp in my code. May be crashlytics has a dependency to it.

Comment: What does the output of your [gradle dependencies](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#view-dependency-tree)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thanks. I could find two dependencies to OkHttp, one through `firebase-crashlytics`, which links to `okhttp:3.12.1`, and the other through `nitrite`, which links to `okhttp:4.3.1`. I think the min SDK upgrade of OkHttp is done in version 3.13, so the newer version which `niterite` depends on should be the problem. Any idea how to prevent taking this new version through `nitrite` dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OkHttp 3.13 or higher [raised the minSdkVersion to 21](https://developer.squareup.com/blog/okhttp-3-13-requires-android-5/) so if you, or **any** of your dependencies depend on any newer version of Android, you must raise your `minSdkVersion` to 21 or higher or drop any dependencies that pull in a newer version of OkHttp.

As per the blog post:

> **Why Android 5+ and Why Now?**
>
> TLS is the mechanism that makes HTTPS calls secure, private, and authenticated. OkHttp is aware of five versions: SSLv3 (1996), TLSv1 (1999), TLSv1.1 (2006), TLSv1.2 (2008), and TLSv1.3 (2018). We dropped support for SSLv3 in 2014 in response to the POODLE attack.
>
> Now it’s time to drop both TLSv1 and TLSv1.1 and to make TLSv1.2 the Internet’s new minimum standard. On October 15 [2018] our colleagues at Google, Mozilla, Microsoft, and Apple announced that their browsers will require TLSv1.2 or better starting in early 2020.
>
> **Google added support for TLSv1.2 in Android 5.0**. Oracle added it in Java 8. In OkHttp 3.13 we require that the host platform has built-in support for TLSv1.2.

So there's a very strong security reason to upgrade to the newest version of OkHttp and raise your minSdkVersion to 21.